# PHP server stops my loop. Why?

Tags: php, loops

I'm trying to verify the `3x + 1 problem`, by running a PHP script online and evaluating all numbers.

I have an infinite loop running, but the server stops my loop when the value reaches about 35,000.

I'm guessing the termination is caused when my HTTP connection resets and the server is no longer serving my request.

I want to have it run as long as it can, eating up the server's resources if it wants to. How do I do it? Cronjobs?

Here's the script, the "End" is never printed.

```
class Collatz_Verify
{
    public function Collatz_Verify()
    {
        // open output file
        $file = 'verified_nums.txt';
        $outFile = fopen($this->NUMBERS_FILENAME, 'a');
    }

    public function verify()
    {
        $num = 0;
        while(1)
        {
            $num += 1;
            # call collatz!!
            if($this->collatz($num) == 1)
                   fwrite($this->outFile, $num);
        }
        print "ah, crap! End!";
    }

    public function collatz($num)
    {
        if ($num == 1)
            return 1;
        if (($num % 2) == 0)
            return $this->collatz($num/2);
        else
            return $this->collatz((3*$num) + 1);
    }
}


// Fire away!
$ver = new Collatz_Verify();
$ver->verify();

?>
```

Comment: Does the server give an error message when the script stops?

Comment: don't run it under a webserver, then. command line php doesn't have resource limits enabled by default.

Comment: Have you tried `set_time_limit`?

Comment: Run it from the command line. Timeouts are imposed (normally) on requests served by a webserver.

Comment: Are you reaching the max execution time? http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Nothing appears. Just started is displayed, then some loading occurs and done. No error, and not the "End" statement. And the output file has numbers till abt 35,000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php has a  max_execution_time limit, If you want it to run for longer, you could try
ini_set('max_execution_time' ,100 ); //Replace 100 with how many seconds you want it to be able to run

Comment: you also in your php.ini file ( usually /etc/php.ini ) look for max_execution_time and edit it there as well

Comment: yeah, it's set to 30 currently.

Answer (score 2):

You could run it from command line... you'll eventually stop due to lack of resources though.

Running from command line will prevent you from having to do the ini_set mentioned just before my post. (see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

Comment: mpaepper's right about the while(1) logic -- but to use php via CLI: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php - http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php

Comment: the easiest way is via ssh, or if you have direct access to the machine or vm, open a terminal

Comment: But why does a script executed from CLI ignore the max_exeution_limit in the php.ini?

Comment: See the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php

max_execution_time 0 (unlimited)  PHP in a shell environment tends to be used for a much more diverse range of purposes than typical Web-based scripts, and as these can be very long-running, the maximum execution time is set to unlimited.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24137/discussion-between-emeacham-and-jaskirat)

Answer (score 2):

The end never prints, because you are in a `while(1)` loop and thus the statement afterwards will never be reached.
Your script is probably terminated because of your settings in `php.ini` for the variable `max_execution_time`

Edit: Try to use the function `set_time_limit()` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php to be able to increase the time in your script.

Comment: oh! interesting. But my web server disabled it. `Warning: set_time_limit() has been disabled for security reasons`. I'll edit the php.ini

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible reasons for PHP to stop executing your loop.

The first is that the execution time limit is reached.
The second is that the maximum nesting level is reached (due to recursion in `collatz()`).

The maximum nesting level is 100 (I'm not aware of ways to change that). The default execution time limit is 30 seconds. You can increase that, as the other answers show.

To find out what the reason is that your script stops, you should set display errors to on and/or check the error log of the web server. Also you could check the output file and start with the last successful number. So if the last number in the output file is 34998 then change the line `$num = 0;` into `$num = 34998;`.

Answer (score 0):

In the `PHP.ini` file there are limits on time for the script to execute/memory that the script can use.

See http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php for full details